# CreateParams Confusion

Tags: c#, handle, intptr, nativewindow, createparams

I am creating a class to simplify designing controls. It's called `ControlDrawer` and has three private fields:

- a `Point` named `_location`
- a `Bitmap` named `_innerImage`
- a `NativeWindow` named `_window`

I have most of the class done, but here's my snagging point (note, `ControlDrawer` implements `IWin32Window`):

```
IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = new CreateParams();
        cp.X = _location.X;
        cp.Y = _location.Y;

        // Code to make it so CreateParams says to display _innerImage

        _window.CreateHandle(cp);
        return _window.Handle;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to fill in the commented part. Can someone help?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Controls are pretty simple to design.  Just inherit from Control, or Panel, etc.  It would probably help if you explained why you have go down this route.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm building a DLL that will make it easier to shorten code (and teach myself advanced coding concepts) and I want to be able to include this in some controls in the future to make it ALOT easier